# Lucene bigrams tokenizer to include punctuation signs

Tags: lucene, punctuation

Is there any chance that I could use Lucene's ShingleAnalyzerWrapper to generate bigrams taking into account punctuation signs (i.e:.\,\;)? Quick example: given the field "one two; three four" would provide 2 bigrams only: (one two) and (three four)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `ShingleAnalyzerWrapper` that uses an analyzer based on `LetterTokenizer`. `LetterTokenizer` breaks the input text at non letters. Something like:

```
public class MyCharAnalyzer extends Analyzer { 

  public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    TokenStream result = new LetterTokenizer(reader);    
    return result;
  }
}

ShingleAnalyzerWrapper myBigramWrapper = new ShingleAnalyzerWrapper(new MyCharAnalyzer());
```

If you wanted better control over what you consider punctuation, you could subclass `CharTokenizer` and override the `isTokenChar()` method.